# How to connect $.ajax-data from textbox input?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for connect the input i search within textbox, into the $.ajax-data.
textbox id=textSearchTB.

(the whole idea from this function is to press search from textbox input, and display the result)

```
function getSearchRecipe() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "WebService.asmx/searchRecipe",
        data: "{id:textSearchTB}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset= tf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var result;
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
                result = data.d;
            }
            else {
                result = data;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                $("#searchResult").append("<div>'" + result[i] + "'</div>");
            }
        }
    });
}

<div data-role="content">
<form id="searchF"> 
<input type="text" id="textSearchTB"/>
<input id="searchRecipeBTN" type="submit" value="חפש מתכון" onclick="getSearchRecipe()" />
</form>
<form id="searchResult">
</form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value in the search box, do:

```
var textInput =  $('#textSearchTB').val(); // Jquery
```

then:

```
data: {id: textInput} // am assuming that the server side method contains an argument named "id"
```

Comment: the search result won't appear, to look in the server side?

Comment: This means you are getting the textbox value. Try do an alert:
alert(textInput) and also alert(data) in the success part.

Comment: i still not manage to see the search redult, any more suggested ideas?